# How to place two submit buttons in form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two submit buttons in one form. I want to call different actions in both buttons. Is there any way to accomplish this without using JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling different actions is not possible without javascript. You could call the same controller action and inside this action determine which button was pressed using the name property:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" />
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" />
<% } %>
```

and in your controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string save)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(save))
    {
        // the save button was pressed
    }
    else
    {
        // the update button was pressed
    }
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Give the buttons different name attributes. Then in your view handler (or equivalent - sorry, not an ASP.NET MVC person), you can check if that button's name is in the HTTP response and act accordingly.

Only one of the submit button names should exist in the response.

Answer (score 3):

Of course there is!
for example, we have following form:

```
<form>
<input name='customer_name' type='text'/>
<input name='update_user' type='submit' value='Update user info'/>
<input name='delete_user' type='submit' value='Delete user'/>
</form>
```

when server gets form request there exists only one parameter in the collection: either update_user or delete_user. depends on what user has pressed.

Comment: relevant but not for the asp.net mvc

Comment: I think you need to edit your post and show how to distinguish one from the other in the server side code.  The answer is only half of what the question asks.